# Oracle week of the year

Tags: oracle, date

Why 12/16/2013 and 12/17/2013  are in different week?

```
alter session set NLS_TERRITORY=AMERICA;
select to_char(to_date('12-16-2013', 'mm-dd-yyyy'),'ww'),to_char(to_date('12-17-2013', 'mm-dd-yyyy'),'ww') from dual
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the formatting models [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510), it states:

- WW - Week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on **the first day of the
  year** and continues to the seventh day of the year.
- W - Week of month    (1-5) where week 1 starts on the first day of
  the month and ends on    the seventh.

01/01/2013 started on a Tuesday last year, not the first day of week.  So in your test case, 12/17/2013 was on a Tuesday also, and a new "week" as oracle calculates it.  Certainly, non-obvious.

Comment: @user3061754 there is a third option: `IW` - the "ISO Week" which calculates the week number based on the ISO standard for this.

Comment: WOW. That's what I want. Thanks a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please write your comment as an answer, I think many people will choose your answer as the one that they are looking for.